# First order Linear ODE involving a piecewise defined functuon

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

How do I solve the initial value problem $ \dfrac{dy}{dx} + y =f(x) $? Here, $f(x) = \begin{cases} 2, & 0\le x\lt 1 \\ 0, & x\ge 1 \end{cases}$

I thought about first proceeding with simply $f(x)$ and then integrating it on each interval. But that gives  $y = \begin{cases} 2xe^{-x} + A , & 0\le x\lt 1 \\ Be^{-x} , & x\ge 1 \end{cases}$ for constants $A$ and $B$. This is not the answer given and further, I can't figure out $B$.

The answer given is  $y = \begin{cases} 2(1-e^{-x}), & 0\le x\lt 1 \\ 2(e-1)e^{-x}, & x\ge 1 \end{cases}$

Where am I going wrong? And how should I proceed with such problems? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Note that $f(x)$ is a sum of heaviside functions, then take the Laplace Transform of the whole equation and solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. Note that the final function has to be continuous at $x=1$. By integration we get
$$y(x) = \begin{cases} Ae^{-x} + 2  &\text{for $0\le x\lt 1$,} \\ Be^{-x} &\text{for $x\ge 1$.} \end{cases}$$
Now find $B$ such that
$$Ae^{-1} + 2=\lim_{x\to 1^-} y(x)=y(1)=Be^{-1}.$$
The remaining constant $A$ should depend on the initial condition. Do we know that $y(0)=0$?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was thinking that it must have something to do with the point x = 1, but didn't know that we have to demand continuity of the solution.